# Extract an Outlook attachment from the clipboard

Tags: vba, outlook, powerpoint

I'm trying to access Outlook attachments from clipboard using VBA to further process the file.

The user copies an attachment to the clipboard (Right click -> Copy), opens PowerPoint, clicks a buttons and gets the presentation inserted a the end of the document.

The key part seems to access the PowerPoint file in the clipboard an save it on the file system.

Can someone help and provide a sample code for this using VBA in PowerPoint?

Many thanks!

---

I've found a way achieve it.

1. Getting filenames: Solution has been posted here: http://www.access-o-mania.de/forum/index.php?topic=17045.15
2. Getting the content

   - file size in clipboard can be obtained by `GlobalSize(handle)`
   - pointer the by `GlobalLock(handle)`
   - content using `CopyMemory(destination, source, length)`

Comment: How does Outlook come into play here?

Comment: As far as I've understood so far, Outlook copies files to the clipboard in a different way compared to the explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the clipboard contents with an app like ClipSpy. Since there is no physical file to be copied, the full file path is not included (no CF_HDROP format). But `FileGroupDescriptor` and `FileContents` formats are there.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to get the file name out of the FileGroupDescriptor, but struggling with the FileContents. Any suggestions where to start reading on how to get and save the file?

Comment: I am not sure you can do that in VBA.